# printf doesn't work, even with newline and fflush()

Tags: c, printf

I'm compiling the below C code with `gcc`. No errors are thrown during compilation or at runtime. I ran through the code with `gdb`, and the answer given in `sum` is correct at the end, yet the `printf()` does not display anything on the screen. I've tried all sorts of combinations of `fprintf()`, `printf()`, and `fflush()`, but nothing works.

What do I need to change so the program will print the result to `stdout`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        int num = 9;
        int i, sum; i = 1, sum = 0;
        while (i < 2 * num) {
                sum = sum + i * i;
                ++i;
        }
        printf("sum: %d\n", sum);
        fflush(stdout);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://ideone.com/Lf7Kod).

Comment: I guess I'll use that site instead of my school's SPARC computer lab then. Thank you!

Comment: I seriously doubt that the problem has anything to do with your use of a SPARC system.

Comment: Then what could it be? I have the code EXACTLY as given above, I compile with `gcc test.c -o test`, and the program simply displays nothing and moves on to let me input another command.

Comment: Just for the record, I posted my answer before I saw your most recent comment.

Comment: _stylistic_ :: what is wrong with for loops, these days := `for(i=1; i < 2*num; i++) {blablablah;}` would be so much more _readable_ ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code is correct, and should print `sum: 1785` for any conforming implementation.

This is a guess (*update: which turns out to be correct*), but ...

You've named the source file `test.c`, and you compile it with:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
```

(or something similar) and execute it with:

```
$ test
```

which produces no output.

The problem is that `test` is a standard Unix command (and also a built-in command in some shells). When you type a command name to the shell, it first looks for built-in commands, then for executables in directories specified in your `$PATH` environment variable.

To execute a command in the current directory, prepend `./` to the name:

```
$ ./test
sum: 1785
$
```

This applies to *any* command in the current directory. There are so many built-in commands that you can't reasonably avoid colliding with them. Cultivating the habit of running executables in the current directory by typing `./whatever` means that name collisions don't matter.

(Don't be tempted to add `.` to the front of your `$PATH`; that's dangerous. Think about what could happen if you `cd` into a directory and type `ls`, if there happens to be a malicious `ls` command there.)

Comment: Ugh, I didn't realize test was a command. This was the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your program. It *has* to work. Try running it with redirection:

```
./a.out > myout
```

..and see if you get any output. If not, I'd suspect there is a problem with some kind of standard library mismatch.

Another option to check would be to build using SUN C compiler as opposed to gcc and see if that works. If it does, gcc is the culprit.